# "without a break in the wall"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> There is no break in the conversation where you can go: "All right
>   then" . You know It is just going on and on ***without a break in the***
>   ***wall.***

(Context: He is complaining about a friend who constantly call him and speak without taking a break or giving him a turn to talk.)

What does "a break in the wall" mean. Is it a fixed phrase? Why not just a "without a break in the conversation" ?

Answer (score 3):

**Without a break in the wall** is not an idiomatic expression, but the speaker (the one complaining) is trying to emphasise that the person he's listening to speaks so much that their words are like a wall which can't be penetrated.

I wouldn't use "without a break in the conversation" as that would de-emphasise the relentlessness of the speaker, since a "conversation" implies that two people are speaking more or less equally. In this case, the complaint is of one speaker totally dominating the other.

Comment: To elaborate, "wall" is  used metaphorically.   It's likely that "wall" has a similar metaphorical meaning in OP's own native language.